# Output LogParser Query as GIF in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, charts, gif, logparser

I have the following code and I'm trying to generate a gif file to display in my ASP.NET webpage.

...

```
 LogParser = New LogQueryClass()
    W3Clog = New COMW3CInputContextClass()
    Try
        strSQL = "select quantize(time, 60) as TimeGenerated, count(*) as Hits " + _
        " from  d:\Logs\W3SVC1\*.log  into abc.gif   where to_lowercase(extract_extension(cs-uri-stem))='aspx' group by TimeGenerated"
        Dim inputContext As New MSUtil.COMW3CInputContextClass()
        Dim outputContext As New MSUtil.COMChartOutputContextClass()
        outputContext.fileType = "gif"

        outputContext.chartType = "Line"

        Dim success As Boolean


        success = LogParser.ExecuteBatch(strSQL, inputContext, outputContext)
```

But I get the following error at ExecuteBatch method

```
Error parsing query: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: 'into' [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
```

The problem is I don't know how to set the correct output context to generate the gif file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of my Error. I was not seeing the forest because of the trees. I moved the query's INTO clause before the FROM clause and now my image is generated. Yu-huu!